# Chrome Dev Tools is not showing response data in custom HTTP response message

Tags: http, networking, network-programming, google-chrome-devtools, netcat

I am using NetCat to return a custom HTTP message.

However, Chrome Dev Tools is not showing my JSON data in the response tab.
Even Postman is telling me the headers are wrong. However, I still get a 200 OK in the browser. I've looked at the MDN docs on HTTP messages and I don't see where I wrote a header value wrong.
How do I insert JSON data into an HTTP message?

I am trying to create my own HTTP messages for self-learning btw. This was working in the past but I can't get it to work now.

Here is my headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: NetCat! 
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: application/json
{"message":"check your cookies!"}
```

If I change content-type to `text/html` and the body to `hello world` that works but not JSON!

Comment: Was able to get it working when I give a space between the headers and body, BUT for some reason, Content-Length seems to be seen as a malformed response header.

Comment: ok after triple checking content-length was just the wrong count. worked in browser and i could see it was chopped. but postman wont render it unless it matches exactly!

Answer (score 1):

The solution here was to make sure `Content-Length` was the correct number and provide a space between headers and body.